# Handlebars question about trimming a string

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, handlebars.js, sharepoint-online, templating

I don't have a way to easily add javascript.  I now how to write the js helper function but I am curious is there a built in way to return a substring value in the handlebar template?  I am trying to remove the last two characters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research I was able to remove the last character which was a "#".  I did it right in the template with the following code:

```
{{#each (split keywords "#") as | prods | }}
  {{prods}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Where does `split` come from? Is this a helper _you_ created?